# MVC 5 Attribute Routing: Removing Unnecessary Route Attribute From Controller Actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I have a requirement where the resources on the home controller should be accessed without the need to enter the name of the controller in the URL. For instance, `index` action should be loaded when I navigate to `mysite.com/` and contact page should be loaded using `mysite.com/contact` and so on.

The controller below satisfies this requirement but I wonder if there is a way to remove Route attributes that have the same name as the controller action?

For example, using `[Route("contact")]` for action contact does not make sense. When I remove this route attribute, the URL is generated as `mysite.com/home/contact` whereas I want this to be `mysite.com/contact`.

```
[RoutePrefix("")] // Remove the name of the controller from the URL
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 


    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    [Route("contact")]
    public ViewResult Contact()
    {
        return View("Contact");
    }

    [Route("about")]
    public ViewResult About()
    {
        return View("About");
    }

    [Route("terms-and-conditions")]
    public ViewResult TermsAndConditions()
    {
        return View("TermsAndConditions");
    } 
}
```

FYI, here is my route config:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and the Application_Start event:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an empty value as the route prefix, I ended up using the route attribute on specific controller actions like the following:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    [Route("contact-us")]
    public ViewResult Contact()
    {
        return View("Contact");
    }

    [Route("about-us")]
    public ViewResult About()
    {
        return View("About");
    }

    [Route("terms-and-conditions")]
    public ViewResult TermsAndConditions()
    {
        return View("TermsAndConditions");
    }
}
```

This ensures that each defined route is accessed from the root of the site.